# when implement Google Analytics in android Studio Project java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.easylogics.device.cooler.heat.minimiser/com.easylogics.device.cooler.heat.minimiser.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.easylogics.device.cooler.heat.minimiser.Splash" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.easylogics.device.cooler.heat.minimiser-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.easylogics.device.cooler.heat.minimiser-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.easylogics.device.cooler.heat.minimiser.Splash" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.easylogics.device.cooler.heat.minimiser-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.easylogics.device.cooler.heat.minimiser-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
    ... 11 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:296)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:263)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:230)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:112)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:65)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:57)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:326)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:508)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4514)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
        ... 8 more
```

$ While my AnalyticsApplication Class is here some time in some devices the following error occur and sometime app running successfully the error occur sometime but on my device it perfectly run.. i dont know that the issue whats is meant me native error and app crashed on classDefNotFound in dexfile while i am include this class in manifest file

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.app.AnalyticsTrackers;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.StandardExceptionParser;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
public class AnalyticsApplication extends  Application{
    public static final String TAG = AnalyticsApplication.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private static AnalyticsApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

        AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this);
        AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
    }

    public static synchronized AnalyticsApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public synchronized Tracker getGoogleAnalyticsTracker() {
        AnalyticsTrackers analyticsTrackers = AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance();
        return analyticsTrackers.get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
    }

    /***
     * Tracking screen view
     *
     * @param screenName screen name to be displayed on GA dashboard
     */
    public void trackScreenView(String screenName) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        // Set screen name.
        t.setScreenName(screenName);

        // Send a screen view.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).dispatchLocalHits();
    }

    /***
     * Tracking exception
     *
     * @param e exception to be tracked
     */
    public void trackException(Exception e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

            t.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
                    .setDescription(
                            new StandardExceptionParser(this, null)
                                    .getDescription(Thread.currentThread().getName(), e))
                    .setFatal(false)
                    .build()
            );
        }
    }

    /***
     * Tracking event
     *
     * @param category event category
     * @param action   action of the event
     * @param label    label
     */
    public void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        // Build and send an Event.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).setLabel(label).build());
    }

}
```

$  And AndroidManifest.xml is

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
```

Comment: add complete manifest file

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have a similar problem now.